# Flask Web Server not working with SocketIO

Tags: python, sockets, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

#### POST UPDATE

I tested this same code on a different machine and it worked perfectly so it is probably a problem with some dependencies or something similar.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@socketio.on('test')
def test(message):
    print(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,host='0.0.0.0',port=8080,debug=True)
```

I saw in the documentation that you can run the web and socket server just by using
the SocketIO.run method.

When I execute my app.py it runs the server but I cannot access with my browser to webpage.

I saw somewhere that using `async_mode='eventlet'` on the SocketIO constructor could help but it threw an error.

> ValueError: Invalid async_mode specified

Comment: No, it's the same. I also tried with different ports and nothing worked.
I am running the file using "python app.py" instead of using flask, if that could be of help.

Comment: What URL are you opening on your browser? Any output in the terminal running the server after you attempt to open the site in the browser?

Comment: I'm accessing via localhost and I receive no output in the console using the browser. But the server receives the socket connections.

Comment: What URL are you using to connect? Can you please answer with the exact URL?

Comment: I use localhost:8080 (127.0.0.1:8080)

Comment: Try changing to a different port. Maybe you already have another thing listening on 8080.

Comment: I tried with 8080, 80 and 3000 already. I suppose I would get an error message saying that the port was already in use

Comment: I think the best thing you can do is find a friend who is more experienced and sit down side to side (or by screenshare) and show them what you are doing. Something you are doing is wrong, but from the information you provided I cannot tell exactly what.

Comment: Probably that's the best option. I had a similar problem on the past with socketio on NodeJS. Thanks.